# how to get the 64 bit google chrome selenium web driver?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

i having problem with software testing with the selenium.normally iam familiar  with the google chrome.  therefore i need to get the web driver of the google chrome 64 bit version. but unfortunate selenium has the only 32 bit version.can you please tell me is there any alternatives to do this or is this compatible with the 64 bit version too.

this is the link that i have used for download.
[Selenium Link](http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.16/)

content of the page

[DIR]   Parent Directory        -
[DIR]   chromedriver_linux32.zip    2015-06-08 12:55:53 2.31MB
fffdb4c098adc2ab61b0e0f5b694f27e
[DIR]   chromedriver_linux64.zip    2015-06-08 14:53:07 2.17MB
fa8e1bc6f9ce474582876653604d675e
[DIR]   chromedriver_mac32.zip  2015-06-08 13:29:32 3.34MB
3ae88facdc6ad1b716820cc5f678a6c4
**[DIR] chromedriver_win32.zip  2015-06-08 12:30:55 2.33MB

3e1b4a91e12a9872a4ed83c9e61c122e**
[DIR]   notes.txt   2015-06-19 16:52:51 0.01MB
5ca0cfcb8ce5303b1006f23e33b1aa71

Comment: You may want to clarify why this is a Programming question. It appears to be off-topic.

Comment: Hi @nuke_infer  What operating system r u using

Comment: my operating system in windows 7 64 bit

Comment: To clarify, there's a 64 and 32 bit version of Chrome itself.  If we use 64 bit version of Chrome on a 64 bit windows system (windows 10) we appear to have issues, as perhaps nuke_infer mentioned.